# Не меняется значение атрибута класса

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, классы, атрибуты

Имеется класс, описывающий дом. В нем, помимо всего остального есть параметр загрязненности (грязь), который является целочисленным.

Имеется класс описывающий жену, который является наследным от класса описывающим человека. У класса жены есть метод, позволяющий убраться дома (-100 к значению атрибута грязи). И в теле кода есть условие, что при параметре грязи 100 и более, запускается метод уборки.

Но параметр не меняется, хотя метод исправно запускается (например уменьшение сытости в следствие уборки). Остальные методы и атрибуты работают и изменяются как задумано.
В чем проблема?

```
import random


class House:

    money = 100
    food = 50
    cat_food = 30
    dirt = 0


class Person:

    def __init__(self, name, satiety=30, happiness=100):
        self.name = name
        self.satiety = satiety
        self.happiness = happiness

    def eat(self):
        self.satiety += 30
        House.food -= 30
        print('{} ест.'.format(self.name))

    def pet_cat(self):
        self.happiness += 5
        self.satiety -= 10
        print('{} гладит кота.'.format(self.name))


class Cat(Person):

    def eat(self):
        self.satiety += 2 * 10
        House.cat_food -= 10
        print('{} ест из миски.'.format(self.name))

    def rip_wallpaper(self):
        House.dirt += 5
        self.satiety -= 10
        print('Кот дерёт обои.')

    def sleep(self):
        self.satiety -= 10
        print('Кот спит.')


class Husband(Person):

    def play(self):
        self.satiety -= 10
        self.happiness += 20
        print('{} играет.'.format(self.name))

    def work(self):
        self.satiety -= 10
        House.money += 150
        print('{} работает.'.format(self.name))


class Wife(Person):

    def buy_food(self):
        self.satiety -= 10
        House.food += 50
        House.cat_food += 10
        House.money -= 60
        print('{} купила еды.'.format(self.name))

    def buy_fur_coat(self):
        self.happiness += 60
        self.satiety -= 10
        House.money -= 350
        print('{} купила шубу!.'.format(self.name))

    def clean_up(self):
        self.satiety -= 10
        House.dirt -= 100
        print('{} убралась в доме.'.format(self.name))


home = House()
husband = Husband('Муж')
wife = Wife('Жена')
cat = Cat('Шерстяное чудище')

for day in range(365):
    print('\nПрошел день {}\n'.format(day + 1))
    print('{}, сытость - {}, счастье - {}'.format(husband.name, husband.satiety, husband.happiness))
    print('{}, сытость - {}, счастье - {}'.format(wife.name, wife.satiety, wife.happiness))
    print('Дом. {} денег, {} еды, {} кошачьего корма, {} грязи'.format(home.money, home.food, home.cat_food, home.dirt))

    cat_choice = random.randint(1, 2)
    if cat_choice == 1:
        cat.sleep()
    else:
        cat.rip_wallpaper()

    if home.money < 500:
        husband.work()
    else:
        husband.play()

    if home.food < 5 or home.cat_food < 5:
        wife.buy_food()
    else:
        wife.pet_cat()

    if husband.happiness < 40:
        husband.play()

    if wife.happiness < 50:
        wife.pet_cat()
    elif wife.happiness < 100 and home.money > 370:
        wife.buy_fur_coat()

    if wife.satiety < 30:
        wife.eat()
    if husband.satiety < 30:
        husband.eat()
    if cat.satiety < 15:
        cat.eat()

    if husband.satiety < 0:
        print('{} умер от голода!'.format(husband.name))
        break
    elif wife.satiety < 0:
        print('{} умерла от голода!'.format(wife.name))
        break
    elif cat.satiety < 0:
        print('{} умер от голода!'.format(cat.name))
        break

    if home.dirt >= 50:
        wife.clean_up()

    if home.dirt > 90:
        husband.happiness -= 10
        wife.happiness -= 10

    if husband.happiness < 10:
        print('{} умер от депрессии!'.format(husband.name))
        break
    elif wife.happiness < 10:
        print('{} умерла от депрессии!'.format(wife.name))
        break

    home.dirt += 5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys 
import random


class House:
    money = 100
    food = 50
    cat_food = 30
    dirt = 0                                    # <---- грязь

    original_stdout = sys.stdout                #
    save_file = open('q1452500.txt', 'w')       #
    sys.stdout = save_file                      # 


class Person:
#    def __init__(self, name, satiety=30, happiness=100):
# -------------------------> vvvvv <---------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, name, house, satiety=30, happiness=100):               
        self.house = house                                                 # +++
    
        self.name = name
        self.satiety = satiety
        self.happiness = happiness

    def eat(self):
        self.satiety += 30
        
#        House.food -= 30
        self.house.food -= 30                                                # +++

        print('{} ест.'.format(self.name))

    def pet_cat(self):
        self.happiness += 5
        self.satiety -= 10
        print('{} гладит кота.'.format(self.name))


class Cat(Person):
    
    def eat(self):
        self.satiety += 2 * 10
        
#        House.cat_food -= 10
        self.house.cat_food -= 10
        
        print('{} ест из миски.'.format(self.name))

    def rip_wallpaper(self):
#        House.dirt += 5
        self.house.dirt += 5                                   

        self.satiety -= 10
        print('Кот дерёт обои.')

    def sleep(self):
        self.satiety -= 10
        print('Кот спит.')


class Husband(Person):

    def play(self):
        self.satiety -= 10
        self.happiness += 20
        print('{} играет.'.format(self.name))

    def work(self):
        self.satiety -= 10
#        House.money += 150
        self.house.money += 150

        print('{} работает.'.format(self.name))


class Wife(Person): 
        
    def buy_food(self):
        self.satiety -= 10
#        House.food += 50
#        House.cat_food += 10
#        House.money -= 60
        self.house.food += 50
        self.house.cat_food += 10
        self.house.money -= 60
        
        print('{} купила еды.'.format(self.name))

    def buy_fur_coat(self):
        self.happiness += 60
        self.satiety -= 10
        
#        House.money -= 350
        self.house.money -= 350
        
        print('{} купила шубу!.'.format(self.name))

    def clean_up(self):
        self.satiety -= 10

# !!! ---------------> !!! <-----------------------------------------------------     
#        House.dirt -= 100            
        self.house.dirt -= 100 
        
        print('{} убралась в доме.'.format(self.name))


home = House()
# ---------------------> vvvv <--------------------------------------------------
husband = Husband('Муж', home)                                     # !!! +++ home
wife = Wife('Жена', home)                                          # !!! +++ home                                               
cat = Cat('Шерстяное чудище', home)                                # !!! +++ home

for day in range(365):
    print('\nПрошел день {}\n'.format(day + 1))
    print('{}, сытость - {}, счастье - {}'.\
        format(husband.name, husband.satiety, husband.happiness))
    print('{}, сытость - {}, счастье - {}'.\
        format(wife.name, wife.satiety, wife.happiness))
    print('Дом. {} денег, {} еды, {} кошачьего корма, {} грязи'.\
        format(home.money, home.food, home.cat_food, home.dirt))

    cat_choice = random.randint(1, 2)
    if cat_choice == 1:
        cat.sleep()
    else:
        cat.rip_wallpaper()

    if home.money < 500:
        husband.work()
    else:
        husband.play()

    if home.food < 5 or home.cat_food < 5:
        wife.buy_food()
    else:
        wife.pet_cat()

    if husband.happiness < 40:
        husband.play()

    if wife.happiness < 50:
        wife.pet_cat()
    elif wife.happiness < 100 and home.money > 370:
        wife.buy_fur_coat()

    if wife.satiety < 30:
        wife.eat()
    if husband.satiety < 30:
        husband.eat()
    if cat.satiety < 15:
        cat.eat()

    if husband.satiety < 0:
        print('{} умер от голода!'.format(husband.name))
        break
    elif wife.satiety < 0:
        print('{} умерла от голода!'.format(wife.name))
        break
    elif cat.satiety < 0:
        print('{} умер от голода!'.format(cat.name))
        break

# ??? ------------> ??? <----------------------------------------------------------
#    if home.dirt >= 50:
    if home.dirt >= 100:
        wife.clean_up()

    if home.dirt > 90:
        husband.happiness -= 10
        wife.happiness -= 10

    if husband.happiness < 10:
        print('{} умер от депрессии!'.format(husband.name))
        break
    elif wife.happiness < 10:
        print('{} умерла от депрессии!'.format(wife.name))
        break

    home.dirt += 5
    
    
sys.stdout = home.original_stdout         # 
home.save_file.close()                    #
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло, хотя непонятно почему, ведь остальные атрибуты работали как надо

Comment: @Влад пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

> помогло, хотя непонятно почему, ведь остальные атрибуты работали как
> надо

На самом деле нет, у вас тут всё работает не "как надо", потому что вы не понимаете разницу между:

- переменными класса
- переменными **экземпляра** класса

`House` - это класс
`home = House()` - это **экземпляр** класса.

Первоначально `home` получает те же переменные, что и сам класс, но в дальнейшем они живут своей отдельной жизнью. Поэтому когда вы проверяете переменную (поле класса) `House.<поле>`, а затем меняете переменную `home.<поле>`, то вы обращаетесь к **двум разным** переменным. Тут возможны два решения этой проблемы:

- либо вы не создаёте экземпляров класса - у вас будет строго один дом `House` и вы работаете с ним строго через название класса
- либо вы создаёте экземпляры класса и работаете с ними, но тогда те объекты, которые с ними работают, должны как-то получить ссылку на экземпляр класса, например как в ответе S.Nick передачей этой ссылки в конструктор классов, которые будут им пользоваться, и это наиболее правильный способ, ну либо можно сделать передачу через параметр метода, которому нужна эта ссылка, например:

```
    def clean_up(self, house):
                       ^^^^^ передали ссылку на экземпляр класса
        self.satiety -= 10
        house.dirt -= 100
        ^^^^^ обратились к нему
        print('{} убралась в доме.'.format(self.name))
```